# Retrieve Contacts from Components via REST API

Tags: contact, restful-api

is there any official REST API in Joomla?
If yes I would like to retrieve Contacts from Components, do you have any advice on how to achieve it?

Comment: If I rightly remember, a new PR has been submitted to J4 for this. Not sure if it is what you'd be looking for...

Comment: You can find further information on J4 API here: https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/25059/crawling-joomla-websites-without-parsing-websites-html/29195#29195

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this component appears to do what you want, https://github.com/techjoomla/com_api

I haven't used it yet, but have been considering it for a project as it looks like it handles the core components.

Terry